# Install keepassX 2 stable on 14.04

Tags: software-installation, keepassx

I'd like to install current version of keepassX (2.0.2) on my 14.04 desktop. I've found a repo (ppa:eugenesan/ppa), but I don't trust it enough to download a password manager from it.

- I don't want to use Keepass from software center, because it uses
  mono, looks clumsy and I use keepassX 2.0.2 on other platforms.
- I can't use keepassX 0.4.3 from software center, because I migrated to .kdbx database.

Keepassx website offers a tar.gz file ([Keepassx website](https://www.keepassx.org/downloads/)), but I'm not sure how to install it. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a very good idea to not trust a package from a ppa! :D For installing the tar.gz there are [detailed instructions on the official website](https://www.keepassx.org/dev/projects/keepassx/wiki/Install_instructions), what is your problem with them exactly?

Comment: I'll add that I found their instructions remarkably clear and easy to follow.  Rather then running `make install` I use `checkinstall` which creates a small .deb file that I can use to install locally, or remove at a later date.

Comment: I'm not sure about these: cmake .. [CMAKE PARAMETERS] and
make [-jX]. What are the exact commands needed here?

Comment: I have 16.04 and it is using the new KeyPassX v2.0.2 Also uses Qt 4.8.7 and libgcrypt 1.6.5. So you may need other updates also.

Comment: Leave the CMAKE parameters alone, and use -j for compiling.  The -jX indicates to use X number of threads when compiling, and there are a large number of C parameters that could be used.

Comment: have you installed it now?

Comment: I just installed it through synaptic package manager. Is that safe? I tried using ubuntu software center but it kept asking me for U1 login info and kept saying it was invalid. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and it installed 'keepassx 2.0.2'

Comment: There is a similar question where I provided almost the same answer, please close one of these. http://askubuntu.com/q/849321/40581

Answer (score 2):

I installed it from source by [following the instructions](https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx) on the GitHub repository, which worked fine when I was still using 14.04.

> ## From Source
>
> ### Build Dependencies
>
> The following tools must exist within your PATH:
>
> ```
> make
> cmake (>= 2.8.12)
> g++ (>= 4.7) or clang++ (>= 3.0)
> ```
>
> The following libraries are required:
>
> ```
> Qt 5 (>= 5.2): qtbase and qttools5
> libgcrypt (>= 1.6)
> zlib
> libxi, libxtst, qtx11extras (optional for auto-type on X11)
> ```
>
> On Debian you can install them with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake qtbase5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools libgcrypt20-dev zlib1g-dev libxi-dev libxtst-dev
> ```
>
> Build Steps
>
> To compile from source:
>
> ```
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake ..
> make [-jX]
> ```
>
> You will have the compiled KeePassX binary inside the `./build/src/` directory.
>
> To install this binary execute the following:
>
> ```
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> More detailed instructions available in the INSTALL file.