# KeePassX fails to install on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, libgcrypt, keepassx

I am trying to install KeePassX. I downloaded the source from their website but whenever I try the following

```
sudo cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<build> -DWITH_GUI_TESTS=ON
```

I get the following error

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Gcrypt (missing: GCRYPT_LIBRARIES GCRYPT_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindGcrypt.cmake:31 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:157 (find_package)
```

tried googling the error but nothing useful came up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are missing some libraries for compiling.
Before running cmake you can try installing `libgcrypt20-dev` or `libgcrypt11-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libgcrypt20-dev
```

Then run cmake again.

By the way, what's wrong with installing it from the official ubuntu repository?

```
sudo apt-get install keepassx
```

Comment: Thanks I just installed it from the Ubuntu repository : )

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you not simply [follow the instructions](https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx)? Why do you have to come up with something discouraged like `sudo cmake`?

> ## From Source
>
> ### Build Dependencies
>
> The following tools must exist within your PATH:
>
> ```
> make
> cmake (>= 2.8.12)
> g++ (>= 4.7) or clang++ (>= 3.0)
> ```
>
> The following libraries are required:
>
> ```
> Qt 5 (>= 5.2): qtbase and qttools5
> libgcrypt (>= 1.6)
> zlib
> libxi, libxtst, qtx11extras (optional for auto-type on X11)
> ```
>
> On Debian you can install them with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake qtbase5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools libgcrypt20-dev zlib1g-dev libxi-dev libxtst-dev
> ```
>
> Build Steps
>
> To compile from source:
>
> ```
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake ..
> make [-jX]
> ```
>
> You will have the compiled KeePassX binary inside the `./build/src/` directory.
>
> To install this binary execute the following:
>
> ```
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> More detailed instructions available in the INSTALL file.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do.

Comment: Obviously not since you used sudo, different parameters and have a missing dependency.

Comment: I improvised because the usual instructions didn't work.